# XPATH Query: How to get two elements?

Tags: xpath

My HTML code is:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="data1"><p>1</td></td>
<td class="data1"><p>2</td></td>
<td class="data1"><p>3</td></td>
<td class="data1"><p>4</td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="data1"><p>5</td></td>
<td class="data1"><p>6</td></td>
<td class="data1"><p>7</td></td>
<td class="data1"><p>8</td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My query is:

```
xpath='//tr//td[@class="data1"][4]/p'
```

The results is:

```
<p>4</p>
<p>8</p>
```

The results is **correct**! but, if I want to get example:

```
<p>3</p> <p>4</p>

<p>7</p> <p>8</p>
```

So

**[3]/p**   and   **[4]/p**

How to get these two elements each `<tr>` ?

Thank you so much!

Comment: something along the lines of [position()] might be useful

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer that corrects your XML and discusses two correct solutions and why a third proposed XPath expression is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you might be looking for is something along the lines of

```
[position() > 2]
```

which retrieves all elements after the first two.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Could I use?


[position() = 1][position() = 4]

if i want to get only the first and the fouth element?

Comment: @Damiano - If you evaluate those two predicate filters separately, you will get the information you want.  If you want to evaluate them in a single XPATH expression, then you will need to combine them in a single predicate filter and use the `or` operator: `[position()=1 or position()=4]` Otherwise, it will evaluate to see if both predicate filters are true(and no element will be both the 1st AND the 4th).

Answer (score 4):

**First notice that the provided XML is not well-formed!**

I assume that intended wellformed XML more or less looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="data1"><p>1</p></td>
        <td class="data1"><p>2</p></td>
        <td class="data1"><p>3</p></td>
        <td class="data1"><p>4</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="data1"><p>5</p></td>
        <td class="data1"><p>6</p></td>
        <td class="data1"><p>7</p></td>
        <td class="data1"><p>8</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For this XML document here are my answers.

**Use**:

`/*/*/td[position() = 3 or position() = 4]/p`

**Or, you can use the XPath union operator**:

`/*/*/td[3]/p  | /*/*/td[4]/p`

**The following is wrong**:

`/*/*/td[3] [4]/p`

This specifies the selection of 4th node of `/*/*/td[3]` and **will select nothing** because `/*/*/td[3]`  only selects two nodes.

**Lastly, here is a transformation that when run demonstrates the result of all XPath expressions above**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=" /*/*/td[position() = 3 or position() = 4]/p"/>

  ----------------------

  <xsl:copy-of select="   /*/*/td[3]/p  | /*/*/td[4]/p"/>

  ----------------------

  <xsl:copy-of select=" /*/*/td[3][4]/p"/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```